# Rules and Negative Assertions in CloudFormation parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, infrastructure-as-code, aws-service-catalog

```
Rules:
  ValidateHostedZone:
    RuleCondition:
      Fn::Equals:
      - Ref: UseSSL
      - 'Yes'
    Assertions:
    - Assert:
        Fn::Not:
        - Fn::Equals:
          - Ref: ALBSSLCertificateARN
          - ''
      AssertDescription: ACM Certificate value cannot be empty if SSL is required
```

The above code should validate if 'UseSSL' is 'Yes',   'ALBSSLCertificateARN' cannot be empty. But this doesn't seem to be working. If I do not use the 'Not' function, the validation is successful. (I won't be allowed to go ahead unless 'UseSSL' is not set in parameters. But, I want just the opposite of it and the above doesn't seem to work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No error message as such! Just that the validation doesn't get applied. It's moving to the next settings when it should've been displaying the validation error. (Note: Removing the Not function, validation works fine, although it's exactly inverse of what I need)

Comment: You are right, CloudFormation does not show the validation error on the parameters page. However, your code seems to be valid. I launched a CloudFormation Stack with that (setting UseSSL: Yes and leaving ALBSSLCertificateARN empty) and it was rolled back with the following error message: `Parameter validation failed: assertion error: ACM Certificate value cannot be empty if SSL is required. Rollback requested by user`.

Comment: @berenbums yeah, the whole point of adding the Rules was to stop "this". i.e., stop user from moving forward if UseSSL is "Yes" and the ALBSSLCertificateARN is empty.

Comment: You know whats weird! The following sample with negative assertion is provided by AWS and it doesn't work as expected: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cloudformation-get-att-from-param/blob/master/GetAttFromParam.yaml